# module not found issue with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a folder structure like this

```
- functions
 - func1
   - file.py
   - app.py
   - file1.py
 - func2
- tests
 - test1.py
```

I am calling app.py inside test1.py

```
def test_file_case():
    from functions.func1.app import some_func
```

and app.py imports file and file1 which throws error when I run `pytest -s test1.py or python -m pytest test1.py`

```
from file import *
from file1 import *
def some_func():
  somecode..
```

any suggestions what could be done to resolve the issue and I have `__init__.py` files in all the directories.

Comment: How do you run the tests ? please write the commander and the root folder from where you run the test suite

Comment: I run the test cases from the folder tests and the command which I use to run test case is pytest -s test1.py or python -m pytest -s test1.py

Comment: and "functions" is right under tests folder ?

Comment: (just by the way : "and I have __init__.py files in all the directories." is not necessary. Only one at the root folder)